# keyboard shortcut to add myself to BCC

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I want a keyboard shortcut that will add my email to the bcc field when authoring an email. The reason is because I then have a rule to move such emails to a "waiting for reply" folder. How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you are allowed to do VBA macros in Outlook, you could do it that way I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a macro that does what you want, and add a shortcut key to it.
(You will need to enable macros in outlook for this to work)

Create a new macro:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865785.aspx

Paste this code:

```
Public Sub AddMeToBcc()

    Dim objRecip As Recipient
    Set oInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
    If Not oInspector Is Nothing Then
        Set oMsg = oInspector.CurrentItem
    Else
        Set oMsg = Application.ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse
    End If    
    With oMsg

        Set objRecip = oMsg.Recipients.Add("XXX@XXX.com")
        objRecip.Type = olBCC
        objRecip.Resolve

    End With    
    Set oMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Change "XXX@XXX.com" to your email address and save the macro.

Add the macro to quick access toolbar and find out what is the shortcut key:

1. Open a new message, on the top left there are the quick access toolbar icons.
2. Click the small down arrow to "Customize the quick access toolbar"
3. Click "More Commands..."
4. Instead of "Popular commands" select "Macros". You should see the new macro you created. Select it.
5. Click "Add >>" (between the 2 panes)
6. Select the macro you added in the right pane, click "modify" to rename and iconize it
7. Click "Ok". You will now see your macro button in the quick access toolbar.
8. Click "Alt" and you will see the shortcut key assigned to it
9. Now to add yourself to the Bcc - you press "Alt+[Keyboard Shortcut Number]"

Enable macros:

Step 1: Click the File > Options.

Step 2: In the Outlook Options dialog box, click the Trust Center in the left bar.

Step 3: Click the Trust Center Settings button.

Step 4: In the Trust Center dialog box, click the Macro Settings in the left bar.

Step 5: In the Macro Settings section:

To enable all macros, please check the Enable all macros (not recommended; potentially dangerous code can run) option.

Comment: When I do this from the inline message editor (that appears in the preview pane), I get an error: 'Object variable or With block variable not set' on the line 'Set oMsg = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem'